# Can we starve to death?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can we starve to death in Minecraft?

If the character have an empty hunger bar, will the health bar diminish until his death?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer can be found on the minecraft wiki page on [hunger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger).

If you have 90%-100% food you will regain health slowly, but if you have 0% you will lose health instead. On easy the player's health would slowly drop to 5 hearts, 0.5 hearts on normal, and all the way to death on hard.

Comment: In other words, when your food bar falls to 0, in hard mode your health bar does indeed reduce to 0 (death), but in easy and normal modes, it only reduces to a *minimum value* of 5 and 0.5 respectively, after which it stops (course having minimal health makes it easier to die from other things).